# How to share large files between users

Tags: file-sharing, online-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best site for sharing large files among a specific group of people?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2996/what-is-the-best-site-for-sharing-large-files-among-a-specific-group-of-people)

I want to be able to share files between a small group of people. Each has about 100 files that are up to 2 GB each.

I could upgrade Dropbox for 100GB but I don't think it allows others to upload files to it, unless I give them the password, right?

Comment: "Each user"? So the total amount you need to share is potentially 200GB * no_of_users? Are torrents an option?

Comment: You can upgrade to 100GB, share a folder and everyone can upload and download from there. No password sharing needed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if they don’t have access to the 100GB Dropbox account, how could they upload anything to it?

As for sharing the files, you could use Google Drive. See the [*How to share*](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494822) man page for instructions.

Also, if you need this for a limited period of time and you don’t want/like Google Drive, you could use the free trial option of [YouSendIt](http://www.yousendit.com/compare-plans).

Answer (score 0):

I find [Wetransfer](http://www.wetransfer.com) a great way to send large files (up to 2gb / transfer)
Its free and you dont even need to create an account.

Comment: Downloads are often rather slow for me (around 200 KB/s), see also https://wetransfer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202607926-The-download-speed-is-slow