# How to attach EXE file in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send a windows executable via Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/how-can-i-send-a-windows-executable-via-gmail)

Why doesn't Gmail allow to attach EXE files? It's very annoying.
Gmail even denies if I archive the .exe file to .zip.
Why did they decide to do that?

How do you do it when you want to attach an EXE file?

Comment: Since you are not comfortable with any of the solutions below(Mehper C. Palavuzlar's), I think you should ask the person in the receiving end to download necessary file from where you downloaded originally.

Comment: An encrypted 7-zip archive inside a normal ZIP archive works for me without any renaming.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to the new GMail AntiVirus Scanner, you cannot send or receive emails with **exe, dll, ocx, com** or **bat** attachments even if they are sent in a zipped **(.zip, .tar, .tgz, .taz, .z, .gz)** format (The **.rar** format is still allowed).

> Since you cannot Turn Off GMail
>   AntiVirus Scanning, you can use these
>   GMail hacks to send program file
>   (exe), virus samples and other blocked
>   formats with GMail:
>
> 1. **Use a free file hosing online service** like Rapidshare, Megaupload or
>      Yousendit to upload your file and send
>      the link of the uploaded file in your
>      GMail message.
> 2. **Rename the file**: Change the file extension to fool the GMail scanner.
>      The new attachment could contain
>      instructions making it easier for the
>      recepient to derive the actuall
>      attachment type. For instance,
>
>    Rename `Adobe-Reader.exe` to
>      `Adobe-Reader.exe.removeme`
> 3. If you have lot of exe files to send, **put them in a zip file and
>      change the extension of the zip file**
>      as mentioned in the previous step.
>      Remember that GMail denies zip
>      attachments that contain exe files.
>      Pass-Protection won't work either
>      since GMail can examine exe filenames
>      even in password protected zipped
>      files as the archived filename
>      listings are not encrypted by the Zip
>      program.
> 4. **Use a different compression software like WinRAR** which compresses
>      files in .rar format. GMail is
>      currently not scanning or blocking
>      .rar filetypes. But there is a high
>      probability that GMail might support
>      rar formats in future. In that case,
>      you can consider splitting the rar
>      files and attaching them separately
>      (like .r1, .r2..)
>
> **Important:** I would recommend only the
>   first technique since all others
>   violate Google policies and Google
>   could even terminate your GMail
>   account.

**Source:** [Attach and Send Any File Type with GMail Like EXE, ZIP, Videos; Trick GMail Antivirus Scanner](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2005/12/cheat-gmail-antivirus-scanner-attach.html)

On 05/14/2012 (today), I attempted to upload a .rar file that contained a .vb file - one of Googles banned file types. gmail does not allow .rar files containing banned file types anymore either.

Comment: Thanks Mehper. IMO, **tip1** has big drawback. It depends on other services. I want to save attachment file in gmail but not other service. **tip2,3,4** makes people who receive mail uncomfortable. They should rename again, and have to install RAR if they don't have it. Any better idea?

Comment: @Benjamin: Sorry but I can't think of any other solutions better than these...

Comment: I don't think that you're violating anything.. (correct me if I'm wrong) It's against their policy to rename the files or use other archiving tools than Zip? They just want to protect the users by accidentally opening the file right away.. but if it is renamed is stopping being executable and it's up to the user what to do with the file! They are not going to terminate your account because of that..(I think)

Comment: ya, we change zips to .piz files at work, and it seems fine

Comment: @Lipis: The violation issue is not totally reflecting my thoughts neither (I quoted it from the related article). I just added that in case Google's policy includes such conditions. It would be better if someone who read the related Gmail policies could enlighten us.

Comment: Any idea why `.rar` is allowed?

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: the `.rar` and `.zip` are no longer allowed with or without password and/or filename encryption. I had this problem and as someone suggested, `.7z` is they way to go. About the terminating your account because of policy violation: you should remember that the internet should be free, just create another email account and you're done.

Answer (score 5):

Another method glossed over in @Mehper's article - zip it with a password.  The .zip format supports encrypting the filenames in addition to the files, so gmail will not be able to tell the file contains an executable.

Just make sure you tell the recipient the password!

Comment: Pass-Protection won't work either since GMail can examine exe filenames even in password protected zipped files as the archived filename listings are not encrypted by the Zip program.

Comment: @Mehper:  That is not true;  I use this method to transfer .exe files through gmail.  You just need to have a zip-program that supports encrypting the filenames as well (I know Winrar and Winzip do)

Comment: ZIP files does not support filename protection *by definition*, no matter what software you use. You probably compressed your files to **RAR** that supports this feature.

Comment: @Isaac: Nope, it's definitely zip.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Open one of your password protected files in WinRAR - You'll be able to see the filenames before entering a password. It's part of the Zip file spec. It's possible that Google just sees the password and gives up, but the filenames are definitely not encrypted

Answer (score 2):

apart from the two answers already given...

i highly recommend simply looking for a better email provider, which respect our freedom, and do your own backups anyway! (you can read more about it on my profile)

but in case you still insist with gmail, your only option is to use encryption, such as compressing the file with a password as suggested in the main answer, or a file sharing which allows for such things (google drive doesn't).

neither can really get you in legal trouble. both can lead to account suspension. big corps don't care to terminate anyone's account.

ps: i heavily edited this answer to update my opinion.

pps: i've tested all this using a procedural generated art exe, which is considered a malware by google https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=59106

Comment: +1 for *Hopefully this will get integrated with gmail someday.*

Comment: `-1` This is not what the author asked. He wants a regular e-mail with a normal attachment that is part of the message, rather than a dependency on a third-party resource or another service from the same party that requires a browser, in addition to an e-mail client.

Comment: @ant_222 you're both so right and so wrong at the same time... yes, everything you said is true. but nowadays i only care for anything google do as much as i care for keeping away from them! and if i want a "regular email with a normal attachment", i would never look for any big corps. what's more, we're collectively creating better alternative to emails already. ever heard of the fediverse? it's only missing, basically, broader adoption! but, also technically, it's not as easy to find a good #offlinefirst client for it. yet. thanks for your feedback, and cheers!

Comment: Does *fediverse* support a one-to-one plain-text asynchronous communication? If not, then it cannot replace *e-mail* yet.

Comment: yes, it does. it may never replace email. it never intended to.