# How to send Gmail attached 7z compressed files containing executables?

Tags: encryption, gmail

I used to be able to encrypt JS files and filenames and send over Gmail. But I just found I cannot do it anymore and it is saying there are executables found in the compressed file. How could Gmail detects file contained in an encrypted package with filenames also encrypted? And is there any workaround?

Update:
After reading the answer in the [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67396/how-does-google-know-that-a-password-protected-zip-contains-a-virus) provided by @Blind Spots, it seems like no encrypted file can be send (I also tried myself).

Comment: The solution I found was http://wetransfer.com

Comment: @Nick That is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Gantendo why? It works.

Comment: @Nick It is rather inconvenient compared to the method I posted below. WeTransfer is full of ads and trackers.  WeTransfer is also quite buggy.

Comment: Easy, rename the exe extension to something like jpg, it will send now. Receiver has has to rename them back.

Comment: @moab you should add that as an answer since it is a totally different  approach than what harrymc suggested.

Comment: @moab When I said the filenames are encrypted, I believe the extension is hidden also. This is why I do not understand how gmail can detect these JS files.

Comment: Likely the mere fact that the information is obfuscated is triggering the behavior.  Here is a very old link about similar issues that may provide a good starting point.  I don't have time to review right now but seemed on topic https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67396/how-does-google-know-that-a-password-protected-zip-contains-a-virus

Comment: " I believe the extension is hidden also" You would be wrong.

Comment: @GabriellaChaos look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_signature and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Moab I tested it, that does not work... It says it is blocked for safety reasons...

Comment: @Gantendo did you encrypt the files? As I read the gmail help page, it says it blocks all encrypted files. I just tested that I can send using the Moab 's approach . The only issue is that when there is large amount of (different kinds of) executables, I have to write a script to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem and didn't find any workaround for it.
Gmail is now much more strict about attachments.

My solution was to upload the file to some online service,
in my case Dropbox, and transmit instead a shared link to the file.
Note that the generated link should be as anonymous as possible
and the file should be uploaded to a publicly accessible section of
your online service storage.

Comment: @Gantendo: Google Drive is a specific example of the recommendation made by harry "upload the file to some online service, and transmit instead a shared link to the file"

Comment: I see this option. However I am expecting a more direct way, i.e. not depending on other applications. But I do not want to manipulate too much, e.g. revert the binaries and output to a txt as hexadecimals. I will accept your answer if no better approach answered.

Comment: @BenVoigt Difference is that it is built in and doesn't require you to switch to a new tab and share your file with yet another company.