# How to enroll in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have Cox email. I need to send a very large attachment (14MB). Upon trying to send the message with the attachment, I get a return message that says the message is too large. Is it possible to switch to Gmail to send the large message? Please assist me. I am not very computer savy.

Comment: First step to computers: Please do not post personal information on the internet, we can assist without it.

Comment: To create a Gmail account, follow the steps from here: https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail

Answer (score 5):

GMail allows attachments of up to 25MB (see [this link](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8770))

If sending still fails, make sure that the recipient can also receive large attachments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gmail to send it. Gmail's maximum attachment size is **25 MB**. Enrolling in Gmail is quite straight forward.

Go to http://gmail.com. Click the red **Create Button** and follow the 3 simple steps.

Then click the gear icon [image: Gear] in the upper-right, select Settings and select the [Accounts and Import tab](http://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts)

In the Check mail using POP3 section, click **Add POP3 email account**.

Enter your **COX email address** then click Next Step.

Gmail will populate sample settings for the **server name** and **port**. Please use these instead

Server: **pop.cox.net**
Port: **110**

Enter your **Password**.

*Do check* Leave a copy of retrieved messages on the server

Click **Add Account.**

Once your account has been added successfully, you'll have the option of setting it as a custom From address. This allows you to compose messages in Gmail, but have them appear to be sent from your other email account. Click Yes to set up a custom From address. (See below for more information)

Go back to http://gmail.com (if you logged out, sign back in)

Click the gear icon [image: Gear]in the upper-right, select Settings and select the [Accounts and Import tab](http://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts)

Under Send mail as, click **Add another email address**.

In the 'Email address' field, enter your name and COX email address.

Choose to use Gmail's servers to send your mail

Click **Next Step >>** and then click **Send Verification**. Gmail will send a verification message to your COX email address to confirm that you own it.

Open your *COX email account* and either click the link in the message Gmail sent or *enter the confirmation code* in the Accounts section of your Gmail settings.

---

There are also some options for attachments larger than 25 MBs at [How to send big files via email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/how-to-send-big-files-via-email)

**References**
<sub>http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370</sub>
<sub>http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21289</sub>
<sub>http://ww2.cox.com/residential/idaho/support/internet/article.cox?articleId={a8fb24c0-6440-11df-ccef-000000000000}</sub>